# Usage of Google/Yahoo API calls in Android app

Tags: android

I want to use Yahoo/Google APIs in my application. Are there any restrictions to using these API calls? Or can we use these APIs by registering with their site/API?

Please let me know if any permissions are needed for free apps.

Answer (score 0):

For google maps you need to get an api key. simple job. I used yahoos api for getting location by sending lat and long, that needs nothing.